# Sending Polish characters with PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters, polish

I have an issue and I can find a lot of questions about this issue on this board.
I would like Polish characters by POST :

When I send with a form by POST the following data:

```
Ciało wielbłądów osiąga długość do 3 m. Ich szyja jest długa, łukowato wygięta; głowa długa,
```

PHP displays the following:

```
&lt;p&gt;CiaÅ‚o wielbÅ‚Ä…d&amp;oacute;w osiÄ…ga dÅ‚ugoÅ›Ä‡ do 3 m. Ich szyja jest dÅ‚uga, Å‚ukowato wygiÄ™ta; gÅ‚owa dÅ‚uga,
```

Even when directly doing:

```
exit(print_r($_POST));
```

At the top of the page.

---

**What have I done so far?**

I tried to use HTML entities

```
exit(htmlentities($_POST['EditorField'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

I tried to use utf8_decode

```
exit(utf8_decode($_POST['EditorField']));
```

I have set the internal encoding at UTF-8 :

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

This takes place very early in the frameworks initialization class.
I hope there is something that I have missed and could be working anyway.

**Edit:**

I added the following :

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

**accept-charset="utf-8"**

And I removed the TinyMCE editor

Still no luck!

```
CiaÅ‚o wielbÅ‚Ä…d&oacute;w osiÄ…ga dÅ‚ugoÅ›Ä‡ do 3 m. Ich szyja jest dÅ‚uga, Å‚ukowato wygiÄ™ta; gÅ‚owa dÅ‚uga
```

**Edit:**
In the mean time I did find the following:

Adding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This does the trick for the $_POST to be correctly send.
I thought that this was the same as :

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

But I was wrong.

There is a small problem that still occurs though.
When saving the data with PDO it still truncates the data.

I my opinion I still use the correct settings to initialize the connection

```
///########==================================================
///######## SET OPTIONS FOR PDO IN ARRRAY FORMAT        
///########==================================================
$options = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT                =>      true, 
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                   =>      PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE        =>      PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND        =>      'SET NAMES utf8'
                );
///########==================================================



///########==================================================
///######## TRY CONNECTING WITH THE PDO DATABASE
///########==================================================
try {
    ///######## MAKE THE CONNECTION AND ASSIGN IT TO : DBH
    self::$DbConnection[$ConnectionName] = new PDO(
                                                        $dsn,
                                                        self::$DbCredentials[$ConnectionName]['username'],
                                                        self::$DbCredentials[$ConnectionName]['password'],
                                                        $options
                                                    );
    ///######## SET UTF 8
    self::$DbConnection[$ConnectionName]->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
}
///######## CATCH ANY ERRORS
catch (PDOException $e) {
    ///######## IF ANY ERRORS JUST SHOW THEM
    ///self::$error = $e->getMessage();
    exit(self::errorField('<strong>PDO database connection error</strong><br />'.$e->getMessage()));
}
///########==================================================
```

(* still I make a mistake somewhere of course. But now I have to find it... *)

> **Solved!!** I hope someone could still up me this post because I found the solution. And it lays in a total different direction than
>   all other noted problems on this board:
>
> Required :
>
> ```
> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
> mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
> ```
>
> BUT REMOVED!! :
>
> ```
>                         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND        =>      'SET NAMES utf8'
> ```
>
> I also removed :
>
> ```
> self::$DbConnection[$ConnectionName]->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
> ```
>
> Tried both of the mentioned above individually. But now it works.

Comment: What does you form / input box look like? the posted results look to have a encoded <p> tag at start, do you have any type of JavaScript formatting running on the input field that could be adding this?

Comment: I use a TinyMCE Editor. Good point BTW!!

Comment: I would try removing TinyMCE for now to see if its that that messing it up, you could also try adding  `accept-charset="utf-8"` to your form tag if it is not already there.

Comment: Tried both. (* after your comment ;-) *) unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Is the file itself (both, the one with the form, and the other one that is processing it) saved in UTF-8? `mb_internal_econding` or `meta charset` might not help if the file itself is not saved with the same encoding.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)